# Get mysql result based on date and count() in Symfony

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have  4 relevant tables in this situation

USER

-userId

GROUPMEMBER

-userId
 -groupId

POST

-groupId
 -dateCreated

POSTBUMP

-userId
 -postId

I want to create a function getTrendingPosts($user_id, $date) where $user_id is the current user and $date is how far back from the current date I want to include results from.

So the idea is to

first get the groups that the user is in

second get the posts that are in the groups we found for the user and are within the time range

third order those posts based on the count() of the postbumps

I can do the first two bits ,but I can't really figure out how to do the third. At the same time, I don't want to use 3 queries if its possible to do it in 2 or even 1.

for the first one, (returns group entities which contain the id)

```
public function getGroupsIdByUserId($user_id){
    $qb=$this->repository->createQueryBuilder('x');
    $qb->select('AppBundle:GroupMember');
    $qb->where('x.userId = :userId');
    $qb->setParameter('userId',$user_id);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

for the second one( I end up calling it for each group id, trying to get it all at once though)

```
public function getPosts($group_id, $date){
    $qb=$this->repository->createQueryBuilder('x');
    $qb->select('AppBundle:Post');
    $qb->where('x.dateCreated < :dateCreated AND x.groupId = :groupId');
    $qb->setParameter('dateCreated',$date);
    $qb->setParameter('groupId', $group_id);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

The queries are done using a query builder function through symfony, although I'm more concerned about the actual logic of the queries so even an answer in plain SQL is good enough.

Comment: `I can do the first two bits` --> show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic SQL you want is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(POSTBUMP.postId) 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN POSTBUMP ON POSTBUMP.postId = postID AND userID = 1
WHERE datecreated < '2017-01-01' AND 
groupID IN (SELECT groupid FROM groupmember WHERE userid = 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(POSTBUMP.postId) DESC
```

To achieve this in one function you could do something like this:

```
public function getTrendingPosts($user_id, $date){
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $qb2 = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:GroupMember')->createQueryBuilder('o2');
    $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder('x');
    $qb->select('count(o.postId), o.postId')
        ->from('AppBundle:Post')
        ->innerJoin('AppBundle:PostBump', 'o', 'WITH', 'o.userId  = :userId AND o.postId = x.postId')
        ->where('x.dateCreated < :dateCreated')
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(
            'x.groupid',
            $qb2->select('o2.groupid')
                ->where('o2.userid = :userId')
                ->getDQL()
        ))
        ->setParameter('dateCreated',$date)
        ->setParameter('userId',$user_id)
        ->addGroupBy('count(o.postId), o.postId')
        ->addOrderBy('count(o.postId)', 'DESC')
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I haven't tested this code so let me know if it works with/without modification.

Comment: will do I'll fire up the server now

Comment: well I want to retrieve posts with the most post bumps and it seems that your sql code returns just the count, your logic however seems to be on the right track. I'll see if I can figure it out

Comment: It's ordered by the count in a descending order. So what exactly does most post bumps mean?

Comment: a post_bump is a similar to a "like". I want to get the posts with the most amount of likes, not the amount of likes themselves

Comment: Also I took a look at my original question and I honestly worded it very poorly.  I also took out some of the complexity by dividing it up into different portions and what not. I put it here if you would want to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023815/get-trending-posts-from-database-symfony-query-builder-mysql?noredirect=1#comment73134915_43023815

Comment: The answer on that question pretty much sums up what you want. Also you should not post multiple questions essentially asking the same thing. You should edit new details in the original questions itself since you are still pretty much ring to do the same thing