# Get trending posts from database - symfony query builder - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I'm trying to make a query which has to combine information from 2 different tables and I'm having trouble with the logic.

Here are my tables,I'm excluding some of the irrelevant info

post(groupId, dateCreated)

postbump(userId, postId)

I'm trying to get Posts which are "trending". In other words, I need to get the posts which are

1. In the given groups,(provided by $groups array)
2. After a given date,(provided by $date)
3. Ordered by the amount of bumps they have

This is my function that I am building off of which only gets new posts but it may help provide an understanding of what I am after. Note that the current repository of the code I have is the post repository(for those not familiar with symfony query builder it basically means that it automatically selects from the post table).

```
public function getNewHomeFeedPosts($groups){
    $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('x');
    $qb->select('x');
    $qb->where('x.groupId IN (:groups)');
    $qb->setParameter('groups',$groups);
    $qb->orderBy('x.dateCreated','DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

This is what I have so far, My real issue lies in ordering by the amount of bumps each post has. I'm thinking that a join is going to have to be utilized at some point.

```
public function getTrendingHomeFeedPosts($groups, $date){
    $qb= $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('x');
    $qb->select('x');
    $qb->where('x.groupId IN (:groups) AND x.dateCreated < :dateCreated');
    $qb->setParameter('groups',$groups);
    $qb->setParameter('dateCreated', $date);
    //todo
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

If you aren't familiar with querybuilder syntax then an answer in SQL would be fine.

Comment: That binding in the `in` operator does not seem right.

Comment: what do you mean by binding? The first bit of code works as described so I don't know what issue you may be referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know symfony, so my answer is in sql. You need to join the `post` and `postbump` tables, group by `postid` and count the number of bumps and filter on groups and the date:

```
select p.postid, p.groupid, p.datecreated, count(*) as postbumps
from post p
left join postbump pb on p.postid=pb.postid
where p.groupid in (...) and p.datecreated<...
group by p.postid, p.groupid, p.datecreated
order by count(*) desc
```

Pls also note that you cannot simply bind an array of parameters within the `in` operator as a single value - unless symfony's query builder uses string operations for parameter setting and not prepared statements.

Comment: I'll see if I can implement your logic into my querybuilder. As far as the in operator, I'm fairly certain that the query builder handles the array properly. I'll let you know if its an issue.

Comment: Well I was unsuccessful in my attempt. I understand your logic but the problem is I would end up with several rows with the same post_id and the only thing differing between them would be the post bumps. I need just the post_ids(no repeats) sorted by how many bumps they have. My next train of thought would be to split up the query into two bits where we first count the amount of bumps each posts has and then we join and sort.

Comment: My query returns a single record per postid, since groupid and datecreated are field in the post table and the group by creates the groups. So, I do not really understand your comment.

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK THANK YOU!